# mouseover event firing for no apparent reason?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was doing some security testing on a site I am working on and I came across some behavior that I can't seem to explain.  A simplified example can be seen in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8nz8grj/2/), which contains the HTML:

```
<div id="test">This is a test!</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('#test').mouseover(function(){
       $(this).innerHtml = "test*<script>alert('mouse over fired!');</script>*test"; 
    });
});
```

To my surprise this rendered (without mousing over...):

```
*test"; }); }); });//]]>
This is a test!
```

I thought this was strange so I added an alert [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/p8nz8grj/1/):

```
$(function(){
    $('#test').mouseover(function(){
        alert("</script>");
       $(this).innerHtml = "test*<script>alert('mouse over fired!');</script>*test"; 
    });
});
```

Again, I was surprised because this time my mouseover event fired as soon as the page loaded.  I thought it might be a jsFiddle bug, so I created a [simple HTML document](http://pastebin.com/5JuHgHDD), but it had the same behavior.  I was able to reproduce in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Can anyone explain why this would be happening?

Comment: `alert('mouse over fired!')` is executed because `.innerHTML` parse  (or maybe "evaluate" will be more suitable word) provided string. `*test"; }); }); });//]]>` is in page because `</script>` is interpreted as script's end. What I can suggest is to get rid of HTML tags in code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8nz8grj/7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to:

```
$(function(){
    $('#test').mouseover(function(){
       $(this).html("test*<script>alert('mouse over fired!');<" + "/script>*test"); 
    });
});
```

You need to split up `</script>` so it won't be interpreted as the end of the original `<script>` tag.

Also, `innerHTML` is a DOM property, not a jQuery property. If you want the script to be executed, use jQuery's `.html()` method; assigning to `.innerHTML` doesn't execute scripts. You also got the name wrong, it's `.innerHTML`, not `.innerHtml` -- Javascript is case-sensitive.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/p8nz8grj/9/)

Comment: additionally you can use a &lt; and &gt; to print < and > to avoid closing the script

Comment: No, I want the actual script tag to be rendered

Comment: @AbeMiessler if you want to show `alert` (execute script) on mouseover - then yes. But this is definitely not secure :)

Comment: If you want to excecute the alert script simply add the alert bellow to your .html line

Comment: @xzegga That doesn't work, it shows the brackets literally: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/p8nz8grj/10/

Comment: @AbeMiessler Do you want to excecute alert script or only show this text on your div?

Comment: @Barmar I still suppose that it is what is all about: to display script literally, not executing it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want an alert to appear when that element is mouseOvered.
If that is the case the following code would be:

```
$(function(){
    $('#test').mouseover(function(){
        alert('mouse over fired!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to excecute the alert script and alwais change the div content , you need to include the alert command in you function like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#test").mouseover(function(){
       $("#test").html("test* *test") ;
        alert('mouse over fired!');
    });
});
```